# How can I define an XML XSD type to describe the subset of "double" excluding "NaN" ,"positiveInfinity", "negativeInfinity"

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have an existing XSD where the type for an element is specified as "double", according to the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#double) this restricts the valid values to:

> 1) the non-zero numbers  m × 2e , where m is an integer whose absolute value is less than 253, and e is an integer between −1074 and 971, inclusive.
>   2) In addition to these values, the ·value space· of double also contains the following ·special values·:  positiveZero, negativeZero, positiveInfinity, negativeInfinity, and notANumber.

I am fine with the first part, but I want to disallow/exclude the following:

- positiveInfinity
- negativeInfinity
- notANumber (NaN)

What is the XML XSD syntax/definition to define this new type, that represents "double, except for positiveInfinity, negativeInfinity, notANumber (NaN)'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably achieve this with a `restriction`

```
<xs:element name="myDouble">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:double">
          <xs:minExclusive value="-INF"/>
          <xs:maxExclusive value="INF"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

**Note** : NaN seems to be also stopped by `<xs:maxExclusive value="INF"/>`

> ERROR: Element 'myDouble': [facet 'maxExclusive'] The value 'NaN' must
>   be less than 'INF'.

I've tried it and it work with

```
<myDouble>123.456</myDouble> <!-- OK -->
<myDouble>+1234.456</myDouble> <!-- OK -->
<myDouble>-1.2344e56</myDouble> <!-- OK -->
<myDouble>-.45E-6</myDouble> <!-- OK -->
<myDouble>INF</myDouble> <!-- KO -->
<myDouble>-INF</myDouble> <!-- KO -->
<myDouble>NaN</myDouble> <!-- KO -->
```

Comment: In fact, any range facet, regardless of value, excludes NaN from the value space.

Comment: I was wondering about that, from what I've seen it's only the max range (regardless of value) that excludes NaN.

Comment: XSD 1.1 is explicit:  "NaN is ·incomparable· with any value in the ·value space· including itself." "Any value ·incomparable· with the value used for the four bounding facets (·minInclusive·, ·maxInclusive·, ·minExclusive·, and ·maxExclusive·) will be excluded from the resulting restricted ·value space·."

Comment: Thanks guys, looks like exactly what I was after. I will test this solution then hopefully accept this answer.

Comment: This solution did exactly what I was after, worked perfectly, thanks.